# How to extend magento 2 product rest api

Tags: magento2.2, rest-api

I am trying to get the value of product searchCriteria in the custom module.

By using that value I need to add some data in response API

```
@return \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface
```

Now custom module totally overrides v1/products/ API.

How can I include custom module value in this return type **@return \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface**

Comment: Follow this link : https://bit.ly/3lvda6m

Comment: thank you @RohanHapani. I want to display before items start. Not for every product.